# Why I cant make only one dropdown center in HTML?

Tags: html, css

So basically im making 2 forms, which is login and signup. In both of the form, there is a dropdown menu. In the login page, i wanted the dropdown menu to be centered, and in the signup i want it to be on the left side of the form. Here are coding for both dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <select class="user" name="">
    <option disabled selected>Choose a User</option>
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="staff">Staff</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <select class="gender">
    <option disabled selected>Choose a Gender</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I differentiate the dropdowns by using class "user" and gender". In css, I use this to make "user" dropdown  to be centered in the form.

```
form .dropdown
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then i realised that both of the dropdowns were centered. So instead i tried this, but it doesnt work. It make both of the dropdown menus to the left.

```
form .dropdown .user
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Is there any other way that I can make the "user" dropdown to be centered but not "gender"?
Here are the pictures of what i get rn.
[image]

Comment: You're looking for the child selector: `form > .dropdown > .user`

Comment: i see, but it didnt seem to work for me using the child selector, i managed to get it worked using classname and id from answers down below. thank you btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want to do. Typically, when you want to select just 1 element, you would use an id.

In your case, the hmtl would be:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="user">
  <select>
    <option disabled selected>Choose a User</option>
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="staff">Staff</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="gender">
  <select>
    <option disabled selected>Choose a Gender</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#user
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you want to select by class for whatever reason and you want to make sure you're selecting the correct element inside your form without changing your html, you can use the child selector like this:

```
form > .dropdown > .user
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: using id works perfectly, but i cant seem to make it work using the child selector. If i would use the child selector, i dont have to change anything in the html?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add another classname to one of the `div class="dropdown"` and target it with CSS differently.

e.g

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-a">
        <select class="user" name="">
          <option disabled selected>Choose a User</option>
          <option value="admin">Admin</option>
          <option value="staff">Staff</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown dropdown-b">
        <select class="gender">
          <option disabled selected>Choose a Gender</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

And the in the CSS you can target and style each one of them separately, like so:

```
.dropdown-a
{
  text-align: right;
}
.dropdown-b 
{
  text-align: left;
}
```